# Как применить свойства объекта к другому

Tags: javascript

У меня есть условный объект со свойствами **first_name, last_name, birthday**, но от сервера приходит ещё с другими свойствами, например, с **phone, email, login**

Я хочу применить свойства второго объекта к первому, но нужно применить только существующие свойства из первого объекта.
Надеюсь я правильно объяснил.

Так вот, как это можно сделать? Да можно просто написать:

```
FirstObj.first_name = SecondObj.first_name;
FirstObj.last_name = SecondObj.last_name;
FirstObj.birthday = SecondObj.birthday;
```

Но это не то, буду рад если вы мне напишите какой метод за это отвечает, и скинитесь литературой

Comment: Написать цикл с перебором свойств первого объекта.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно пройтись в цикле по всем свойствам второго объекта. Для каждого свойства проверить, есть ли оно в первом объекте. Если есть - скопировать значение свойства из второго объекта в первый

Сработает и в обратную сторону - пройтись по свойствам первого объекта и проверять наличие свойства во втором объекте

Вариант с использованием [оператора in](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in) и [цикла for in](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in):

```js
let FirstObj = { first_name: "firstName1", last_name: "lastName1", birthday: "birthday1" };
let SecondObj = { first_name: "firstName2", last_name: "lastName2", phone: "phone2" };

for (let key in SecondObj) {
  if (key in FirstObj) {
    FirstObj[key] = SecondObj[key];
  }
}

console.log(FirstObj);
```